# Migrated from FreeNAS. How do I convert my ZFS Zpool into Linux Raid 5 equivalent

Tags: data-recovery, raid, zfs

**TL;DR** - How do I convert my imported Z-pool to a RAID setup (or LMV?) that I'll be able to recover/rebuild when/if a disk fails?

I migrated from FreeNAS.
Had a RAID-Z (equivelant to Raid 5, I think - where one disk can fail) made up of 4 disks.

I moved, recently, to Ubuntu Server and was able to import the Zpool without too much fuss. It's working - I have access etc.

I installed WEbmin for ease, and noticed that the volume isn't showing in the raid section. I can see the individual disks on the partitons sections, but nowhere else.

So it occurs to me. What if a disk fails now. What happens? how will I rebuild it without the GUI. Can I even rebuild it. Is there a way in Webmin to covert the zpool to something it will be able to work with should a disk fail?

**Side note** - the dashboard of webmin is report a pretty huge total storage amount (i only have about 20TB plugged in... 4x5TB zpool disks and a small SSD for OS.)

```
Local disk space    8.95 TB used / 96.63 TB free / 105.57 TB total
```

Comment: Bump any help appreciated. Sweating bullets that I won't be able to recover if a drive fails.

Comment: still searching for an answer to this one - let me know if any further info needed. Even a link in the right direction would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I installed WEbmin for ease, and noticed that the volume isn't showing in the raid section. I can see the individual disks on the partitons sections, but nowhere else.

Because ZFS is not using DM-Raid to manage redundancy.

It's still redundant. Nothing has changed with the file system; you simply mounted it on a different system.

You cannot convert it. You can delete what you have, and set up a new file system, either using btrfs to manage redundancy, or dm-raid. But I see no reason to do so; zfs is supported.

But you cannot use the dm-raid tools, which is what webmin shows in the raid section, to manage redundancy on zfs. You have to use zfs-tools.

Comment: Thank's for clarifying that.
I am used to FreeNAS, where when a disk fails, it alters you and gives you a GUI to easily replace the disk and auto-resilver.
What happens when a disk fails with my current file system? How do I replace the disk and recover? (Totally happy is you have a link to a walk through or something.) Thanks for your time!